# After resetting iPad, will setting it as new update the iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, reset

I have an iPad Air 2 running iOS 8.1, I wanted to reset it without updating it, so I ran the "Erase Contents and Settings" option. Now it is giving me the option to set the iPad as new, will this update the iOS to the latest version or keep it in 8.1?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will keep it in 8.1. Apple won't force you to update or update major iOS versions itself. :)

Comment: Btw, this should actually be asked at http://apple.stackexchange.com :P

Comment: sorry you are right, my bad and thanks man you are correct :)